# How to normalize characters from different languages in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, collation

I get multiple requests every week to make updates an administrative person ought to be able to do simply because they can not look up the person whose record they need to update due to their name being spelled with foreign characters.

I can update the stored procedure that is called when they enter the name to search, and so I am wondering how can I make sql treat 'a', 'á', 'ä', etc. all the same but without having to resort to something like a full text search as that would be a bit overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just needed to add "COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI" after the column name and after the search term.

I didn't previously realize there was a specific collation for accent insensitive.